# Unity3d Parse FindAsync method freezes UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm running a simple Parse `FindAsync` method as show below (on Unity3d):

```
        Task queryTask = query.FindAsync();
        Debug.Log("Start");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Debug.Log("Middle");
        while (!queryTask.IsCompleted) {
                Debug.Log("Waiting");
                Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        Debug.Log("Finished");
```

I'm running this method on a separate thread and I put a load circle on UI. My load freezes (+- 1 second) somewhere in the middle of the `Thread.sleep` method. It's look like when `findAsync` finishes the process it freezes the UI until it complete their job. Is there anything I could do?

Ps: This works perfectly on editor, the problem is on Android devices.

Ps2: I'm running parse 1.4.1

Ps3: I already tried the `continueWith` method, but the same problem happens.

Comment: What Unity version are you using and can you explain what you are trying to do with this piece of code?  Also, are you open for other solutions that doesn't use Parse FindAsync or Thread,Sleep but works?

Comment: If you just do `query.FindAsync()` without the sleeping and logging, does it work on Android device?

Comment: Thats my problem! this line freezes my UI anywhere I call it, could be inside a Thread or an IEnumerator.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerator RunSomeLongLastingTask () {

    Task queryTask = query.FindAsync();
    Debug.Log("Start");
    //Thread.Sleep(5000); //Replace with below call
    yield WaitForSeconds(5); //Try this

    Debug.Log("Middle");
    while (!queryTask.IsCompleted) {
        Debug.Log("Waiting");
        //Thread.Sleep(1);
        yield WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
    }
    Debug.Log("Finished");
}
```

To call this function, use:

```
StartCoroutine(RunSomeLongLastingTask());
```

Comment: Hi David, this was my first code and as my solution, it freezes the UI.

Comment: Try yielding to the next frame instead of a constant time value.

Comment: I already tried an IEnumerator. My problem is the line Task queryTask = query.FindAsync(); If I remove all other lines it still freezes my app.

Answer (score 2):

Making the thread sleep might not be a good idea, mainly because the number of threads available is different on each device.

Unity as a built-in scheduler that uses coroutines, so it is better to use it.

```
IEnumerator RunSomeLongLastingTask()
{
    Task queryTask = query.FindAsync();
    while (!queryTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        Debug.Log("Waiting"); // consider removing this log because it also impact performance
        yield return null; // wait until next frame
    }
}
```

Now, one possible issue is if your task take too much CPU, then the UI will still not be responsive. If possible, try to give a lower priority to this task.

Comment: @user2494863 did it help you? Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: I already tried an IEnumerator. My problem is the line Task queryTask = query.FindAsync(); If I remove all other lines it still freezes my app.

Comment: Then the problem is in your task. Are you sure that Task are supported in Android? Maybe you need to configure them differently because of limited device capabilities.